# MySQL 5.6 SP: Cursor processes only first row and exits (but SQL returns 100s of rows)?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I've got other SPs that do not have this problem.  I am not sure what the difference is.
I have the "not found" handler set up. 
I have the cursor set to a query that returns 100s of rows when executed in a normal sql console.
I have the exit logic if "not found" condition is encountered.
I cannot see why the loop is only executing on the first row of data and exiting.  There are hundreds of rows left which safisfy the query criteria, which are not being processed.

Ideas/suggstions?  Thank you kindly!

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `clientname`.`ProcessIndividualRecords`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  declare FINISHED integer default 0;
  declare v_clientname_id, v_userLastName, v_userFirstName, v_sfdcContactId, v_parentAccountName, v_parentAccountID varchar(120) default null;
  declare INDIVIDUAL_RECORD_TYPE_ID varchar (45) default "012o0000000O94z";

  declare contact_cursor cursor for
          SELECT clientname_id__c, Account FROM sfdc_master_individual_data where AccountId is null;

  /* declare not found handler for looping through all contacts */
  declare continue handler
        for not found set FINISHED = 1;

delete from log1;
open contact_cursor;
        contacts_loop: LOOP
             fetch contact_cursor into v_clientname_id, v_parentAccountName;
              if FINISHED = 1 THEN
                         leave contacts_loop;
               end if;
               select Id from sfdc_facility_all where name=v_parentAccountName into v_parentAccountID;
               if (v_parentAccountId is not null) then
                        insert into log1 (clientname_id, account_name, MSG) values (v_clientname_id, v_parentAccountName, "Using Facility ID");
               end if;
               if (v_parentAccountId is null) then
                /* Try the system */
                        select sfdc_id from system where name=v_parentAccountName into v_parentAccountID;
                       insert into log1 (clientname_id, account_name, MSG) values (v_clientname_id, v_parentAccountName, "Using System ID");
               end if;

                if ( !(v_parentAccountId is null)) then 
                     /*Update the ID in the master record */
                     update sfdc_master_individual_data set AccountId = v_parentAccountID, RecordTypeId=INDIVIDUAL_RECORD_TYPE_ID where sfdc_master_individual_data.CLIENTNAME_ID__C = v_clientname_id;
                else
                     insert into log1 (clientname_id, account_name, MSG) values (v_clientname_id, v_parentAccountName, "NO PARENT ACCOUNT RECORD FOUND");
                end if;


        END LOOP contacts_loop;

        close contact_cursor;
        select * from log1;

END
```

Comment: In theory, everything seems to be correct, so without the structures of the tables and sample data is difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks. I could provide all that.  But trust me when I say I execute the query and it returns a set number of rows. It is the weirdest thing. I'm suspecting I have been running into a bug with the MySQL sp cache? I noticed other inconsistencies where I would be modifying an SP, re-executing, but the change wasn't evident.  Rebooting the process seemed to help.  But that's a real PITA workaround.